new colors after upgrading flutter
I just Upgraded Flutter to 3.22.2 from 3.10.5 and had some components change color to purple. I have nothing set to purple in my code so I don't understand where it is coming from.
I had previously used this code to reset the default color and it was working fine:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color defaultColor = Colors.teal;

const MaterialColor defaultMaterialColor = MaterialColor(
  _defaultColorPrimaryValue,
  <int, Color>{
    500: Color(_defaultColorPrimaryValue),
  },
);
const int _defaultColorPrimaryValue = 0xFF009688;

now I've tried the two fixes in my themeData but none of them is working:
colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.teal),
useMaterial3: false,


Very likely you need to study up on the material2 to material3 transitions.
